# How to prevent XS-Leaks while maintaining usability?

Tags: privacy, javascript, csrf

The methods presented in https://xsleaks.dev/ are based on the fact that malicious Javascript can use Cross-origin requests to infer data by means of faulty status codes, time required, mime type etc. If the server were to check beforehand whether the request contains a legitimate token, and if this is not the case, respond with a universal error message, such leaks could be prevented. However this has an effect on usability, since users can e.g. not share links anymore.

My question: Could the referred header also be checked in order to prevent such leaks and keep the usability?

Comment: Only use the protection on things that require access control? People shouldn't be allowed to "share links" to gated data...

Comment: Look at how Google Drive solves this issue. If the link is for a private resource (existing or not) authentication and authorization is required.

Comment: Another approach is the one taken by mega.nz: the authorization token (the encryption key) is needed to access the resource. Without it, an user can only infer if the resource exists or not. Both approaches allow sharing links.